# Sustainsys/Saml2 - Other authentication along with SAML2 (mixed authentication)

Tags: saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

Previously our web application (NET Framework 4.8) was using Windows Authentication, then we switched to Sustainsys/Saml2 with Startup.cs and OWIN to login.

It turns out that SAML login cannot be used by Task Scheduler/CRON and by external API consumers, because SAML requires human interaction. So SAML must be disable and other Authentication must be used for the following pages:

- background scripts (aspx pages) run by Task Scheduler;
- 3rd party application use some of our APIs GET/POST;

Task Scheduler do not support saml2 and so and external 3rd party apps, they connect via stored in their config login/password.

As far i know SAML2 requires human interaction via web popup (azure in our case) and cannot be automated.

Comment: It turns out that SAML2 itself is not designed for non human interaction, so it is not possible (as far i know) programmatically login with known login and password from 3rd party applications (for example exe files). Some people say to use Web Control and do emulate enter login and password

Comment: maybe it is possible to configure SAML to cover part of the site

Comment: SAML2 uses Azure as Identity Provider

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved by using OAuth (token) along with SAML. If OAuth is put before SAML in OWIN Startup.cs, token API will work even is SAML is activated (i think SAML code see that Thread.CurrentPrincipal is already set, so SAML step is skipped)

```
        using System;
        using System.Web.Http;
        
        using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
        using Microsoft.Owin;
        using Owin;
        
        using BundleTable = System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable;
        ////
        
        [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyApplication.App_Start.Startup))]
        
        namespace MyApplication.App_Start
        {
            public class Startup
            {
                // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
                public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
                {
                    ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
                    ConfigureServices(services);
        
                    OAuthConfiguration oauthConfig =
                        MyConfigurationManager.ReadOAuth();
                    OAuthSetup oauth = new OAuthSetup(app, oauthConfig); 
    /* server + consumer
    IdentityServer 3

  // server. Probably this step can be skipped if use Azure as server
  app.Map(configuration.AuthServerUrl, idsrvApp =>
        {
            idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(options);
        });

    //consumer
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication,  
    app.UseClaimsTransformation */       
                    oauth.Use(); 
        


                    SamlConfiguration samlConfig =
                        MyConfigurationManager.ReadSaml();
                    SamlSetupSustainsys saml = new SamlSetupSustainsys(app, samlConfig);
/*
Sustainsys
app.UseSaml2Authentication(options);*/
                    saml.Use(); 
        
                    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
                    app.RequireAspNetSession();
                    app.UseWebApi(config);
        
                    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
        
                    BundlingConfig.Register(BundleTable.Bundles);
                }
        
                // Add services to the container.
                public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
                {
                    //services.AddMvcCore();
                }
            }
        }
```